# How to pass a Java String to JSP - to title search results

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page with Java searching a local eXist DB. I am looking to pass the value of a Java String to a `<div>` tag in the JSP.

I want to do this so that the title of my results container reflects what the user has searched for.

e.g. “Your search for `containerTitle` has returned 9 matches”

My Code

```
<div class='concept-container result-container'>
<ul class="menu menu-style">
 <li>
    <a href="javascript:;">Concept Bar</a>
    <ul>
        <div id="title">Concept Title</div>
<%

    String containerTitle = userSearchQuery;
```

I am looking to change either Concept Bar or Concept Title into containerTitle. (which stores the string the user has searched for.

Any help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should avoid using Java Inline Code (`<% ... &>`). Sometimes it is necessary, but code like this tends to be less readable, violates separation of concerns and insecure.

To solve your problem, your servlet should place put the needed values into the request:

```
    request.setAttribute("containerTitle", "Your search for Foo Bar has returned 9 matches”);
```

In your JSP, I'd suggest using JSTL to output the value:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <div>
            <c:out value="${containerTitle}"/>
    </div>
```

You are not limited to pass Strings to `setAttribute`. You may create a simple object containing the information and use "dot language" to access the attributes of the object:

```
    <div>
            <c:out value="${searchResult.title}"/>
    </div>
```

I'd suggest reading a good tutorial about JSP programming to dive deeper into the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Use the setAttribute method on [HTTPServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). Then you can either say `request.getAttribute` in the Java code embedded on your JSP page or use `request.foo` to read an attribute called `foo` in the JSP Expression Language.

If you just want to print the value of `containerTitle`, `out.print(containerTitle)` will do but JSP with embedded Java printing code is rather ugly...